# Race condition between two request in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

This is eCommerce site and I'm using mongodb as a database, users can place order and each order can have multiple products. Product is a seperate table that contains quantityLeft of each product. There's a situation that when two concurrent requests comes and tries to buy the same product the ordered items in orders table exceeds the available quantity in product table.

```
Product Table

{
  _id: '56e33c56ddec541556a61763',
  name: 'Chocolate',
  quantityLeft: 1
}
```

In product's table only 1 chocolate left if one request comes at a time it works fine. Request comes check the order.quantity and handle if there's enough product available.

But when 2 requests comes exactly the same time issue occurs both the request query the database to get the product and check the quantityLeft and found that only 1 chocolate is available and passes the check that enough quantity is still present in inventory and places the order. But in actual 2 orders are placed and quantity we have is only 1.

```
Order Table

{
  _id: '60e33c56ddec541556a61595',
  items: [{
    _id: '56e33c56ddec541556a61763',
    quantity: 1
  }]
}
```

I tried to put both the queries to get the Product detail and place order in same transaction but it doesn't work. Something like this

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession({ defaultTransactionOptions: { readConcern: { level: 'local' }, writeConcern: { w: 1 } } })

await session.withTransaction(async () => {
  const promiseArray = order.items.map((item) => Product.find({ _id: item._id }, { session })

  const products = Promise.all(promiseArray)
  
  const productById = {}
  products.forEach((product) => {
    productById[product._id] = product
  })

  order.items.forEach((item) => {
    if (productById[item].quantityLeft < order.item) {
      throw new Error('Not enough quantity')
    }
  })

  await Order.create(order, {session})

}, { readConcern: { level: 'local' }, writeConcern: { w: 1 } });
```

I'm using nodejs (14.16), mongodb as database npm package is mongoose (5.9).

Comment: If you are updating the products and creating/updating the orders _within the same transaction_ - it should work. Note that MongoDB transactions support is available when used with replica-set and sharded clusters only.